# Compute Instance: Best practice for custom Anaconda env

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'd like to use a compute instance as my develop machine.
Are there any best practices on how to handle custom Anaconda enviroments on these machines?

So far, I do it this way:

```
conda create --name testenv python=3
conda activate testenv
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=testenv
sudo systemctl restart jupyter.service
```

--> Reload the JupyterHub in your browser.

Do you see any drawbacks by doing it this way? I know, some special package combinations in the standard env are lost, but I'd like to know what I've installed in my system.
Of course, one could combine it with an `environment.yml`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workaround is the best option as of now. But I know that the Azure ML product group has been working on exactly this problem, but I can't make any promises as to timeline.

I share your dream of an easily configurable data science cloud development environment that allows for Git repo cloning and environment creation w/ a conda yml. We're so close especially given all the press & announcements around Visual Studio Codespaces!

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Currently checking out some recordings from Build 2020. Seems promising indeed.